# Mac OS Big Sur: external keyboard issue

Tags: macos, keyboard, mac-mini, big-sur

I got a problem with my external Mac keyboard. This external keyboard doesn't include an Fn key. So when I switch in options to use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys, the keys don't work as additional to change volume, for example. I understand that it requires an Fn key, which is missing on my original external Mac keyboard, but when I try to use "Modifier Keys" and switch the Fn key to another one and then nothing works. By the way, I use Big Sur Mac OS. Does anybody have any solutions?

Comment: Use Karabiner Elements to do a fuller remap